# Optimization for recursive function required

Tags: c, optimization, recursion

I want to optimize this function so that it can give quick output for input values
(x = 300, y = 120, z = 10).
I thought of storing the values in a 3D array after successive calculation, but was unable to implement that.

Please help. Recursion is too hard to understand!

```
double P(int x, int y, int z) {

    double final;
    if (x >= 0 && (y <= 0 || z <= 0))
        return  0;

    else if (x <= 0 && (y >= 0 || z >= 0) )
        return 1;

    else {     
        final = 0.1 * (P(x,y-1,z)
                       + P(x-1,y-1,z)
                       +  P(x-2,y-1,z)
                       +  P(x-3,y-1,z)
                       +  P(x-4,y-1,z)
                       +  P(x-5,y-1,z)
                       +  P(x-6,y-1,z)
                       +  P(x-1,y,z)
                       +  P(x-1,y,z)
                       +  P(x,y-1,z-1));
        return final;
    }
}
```

In order to calculate `P (300, 120, 10)` the function has to calculate all the possible combinations of x, y, z such that `0 <= x <= 300`, `0 <= y <= 120`, `0 <= z <= 10`. I thought of first creating a 3D array. If the respective arr[x][y][z] is empty I will call the function, otherwise I will just take the value from arr[x][y][z].

Comment: Woo, that is a lot of recalculation I can see going on there, you really do need to implement some kind of caching system.  Perhaps look up how to optimize a Fibonacci recursion calculation for ideas on how to implement your function

Comment: Just like SO is not a "write my code for me" site, we are not an "optimize my code for me" site. How about you go research [memoization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memoization?sort=faq)?

Comment: @MattBall I tried to do so but was unable to implement that, that's why I am asking for help !!!

Comment: No, recursion is not *that* hard, you just need to understand recursion first. :o)

Comment: It is difficult to optimize this problem if we don't know what you're trying to do! Please explain the problem in detail, THEN supply your attempt.

Comment: Did you try passing the 3D matrix as pointer? Another approach (quite poor) would be to make the matrix global.

Comment: And definitely replace `P(x-1,y,z) +  P(x-1,y,z)` with `2*P(x-1,y,z)`.

Comment: You say you were unable to implement the 3D array cache. What went wrong when trying to cache the results in a 3D array?

Comment: @ArjunShankar I was unable to implement that!! I dont know how to do that, thats why I have posted my code here.

Comment: A 3D array is a 3D array. Arrays are built into C. What is there to implement?

Comment: @n.m. - I know it sounds trivial, when put that way. But couldn't there be problems, especially for somebody without much C experience? Maybe OP doesn't know or isn't allowed, or gets a stack overflow when using C99's VLAs (you can't expect a statically allocated array here). Maybe OP doesn't know how to `malloc` things the right way when using the heap instead. Maybe OP doesn't know where to put the cache (it needs to live across calls).

Comment: @ArjunShankar:  I wanted it to look a bit more simple than it really is, so that OP wouldn't hesitate to try.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to build a [memoized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) version of your function. i.e. include a cache:

```
double P_memoized (int x, int y, int z, double ***cache) {

    if (x >= 0 && (y <= 0 || z <= 0))
        return  0;

    else if (x <= 0 && (y >= 0 || z >= 0) )
        return 1;

    else {
        if (cache[x][y][z] < 0.0) /* Negative => uncached.  */
          cache[x][y][z] = 0.1 * (P_memoized(x,y-1,z, cache)
                                  +  P_memoized(x-1,y-1,z, cache)
                                  +  P_memoized(x-2,y-1,z, cache)
                                  +  P_memoized(x-3,y-1,z, cache)
                                  +  P_memoized(x-4,y-1,z, cache)
                                  +  P_memoized(x-5,y-1,z, cache)
                                  +  P_memoized(x-6,y-1,z, cache)
                                  +  P_memoized(x-1,y,z, cache)
                                  +  P_memoized(x-1,y,z, cache)
                                  +  P_memoized(x,y-1,z-1, cache));
        return cache[x][y][z];
    }
}
```

But a caller to `P_memoized` will have to allocate (and later deallocate) the `cache`. This is an unnecessary headache for the caller, so you wrap the memoized function in a wrapper, and call it `P` (like you did earlier). The code below does this, but *remember* it does not check if `malloc` failed (Read about `malloc` [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/malloc.html)):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
double P(int x, int y, int z) {

    double ***cache, final;
    int i, j, k;

    /* Create a cache.  */
    cache = malloc (sizeof (double **) * (x+1));
    for (i = 0; i <= x; i++)
      {
        cache[i] = malloc (sizeof (double *) * (y+1));
        for (j = 0; j <= y; j++)
          {
            cache[i][j] = malloc (sizeof (double) * (z+1));
            for (k = 0; k <= z; k++)
              cache[i][j][k] = -1.0; /* Negative => uncached.  */
          }
      }

    final = P_memoized (x, y, z, cache);

    /* Delete the cache.  */
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
      {
        for (j = 0; j < y; j++)
          free (cache[i][j]);
        free (cache[i]);
      }
    free (cache);
    return final;
}
```

Then you can just use it as you used to earlier, only this time, its much faster:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
  printf ("%f\n", P (10, 5, 3));
  return 0;
}
```

### Fancy caching

If you want to make multiple calls to `P`, then creating and deleting the `cache` each time might not be the best idea. Then you should consider doing the following:

1. Make the cache [a `static` variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable) so that it lives across calls to `P`
2. [Use `realloc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/realloc.html) to dynamically resize the cache when required
3. Don't `free` the cache at the end of `P` (because it will be reused)

Why do you need to dynamically resize the cache? Because, say, the first call to `P` is made with `x==10`. Then the function will create a cache that has a width of 10. Next time, if `P` is called with `x==20` the old cache is no more wide enough. But the old values contained in it are still useful.

[This question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2457567) talk about `realloc`ing a 2D array. You should be able to extend this to your 3D version.

Once you do this, you might want to think about a new problem: The cache never gets `free`d. So it holds on to the memory allocated right until the program exits. Then you might want to have a global cache, instead of a local static one, and provide a separate function to `free` it in the end.

Comment: Sir, that's awesome code !!! But I am still an amateur so most of the code looks fancy to me !!! Can you please guide me or give me some important Wikipedia topics so that I can learn more about it!!

Comment: @Snehasish - You don't need to call anyone a 'Sir' on SO :P. Now: Which part looks fancy? Which lines of code do you not understand? I don't mind editing the answer with an explanation.

Comment: Whats the use of deleting the cache??? If i input several test cases, does deleting the cache is useful then???

Comment: Deleting the cache - The `cache` is dynamically allocated, so it needs to be `free`d (deleted). However, it really depends on you where you do it. If you call `P` multiple times, then it might not be good to create and delete the `cache` in `P` every time. Then you might want to make the cache `static`, so that it lives across calls to `P`. But then you will have to include code to dynamically grow P as and when required.

Comment: "But then you will have to include code to dynamically grow P as and when required" - Please explain this line

Comment: Talking about cache, I'd probably allocate `cache` in one go (i.e. simulate a multi-dimensional array with one big array). `*alloc` family of functions are typically fairly slow to call (though faster than not caching calculations at all) and it would simplify memory management quite a bit (although some extra complexity would be introduced to array subscription -- this sample didn't contain any error detection at all).

Comment: @eq- Right you are. This was just supposed to show the OP a way to get started. I guess I'll mention the error detection as a caveat.

Comment: @Snehasish - I have made an EDIT with some explanation. I commend to you, eq-'s comment also.