# adding additional columns to the matrix

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, 2d

I'm allocating memory for a 2d array dynamically using the below code,

```
int **matrix = (int **) malloc(testVals[m].rows*sizeof(int));
for(int i = 0 ; i < testVals[m].rows ; i++)
    matrix[i] = (int *) malloc(testVals[m].columns*sizeof(int));
```

but I'm in need to add extra rows and columns as per requirements. I'm able to add extra rows like this, where i'm converting the matrix to square matrix

```
for(i = rows ; i < cols ; i++)
mat[i] = (int *) malloc(cols*sizeof(int));
```

but how to do that for adding columns?

Comment: how is `textVals` declared?

Comment: those are accessing the structure.. its just the number of rows and columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [realloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/) on each row if you need to add a column:
That is, if you need to add N columns, you realloc each row by extending each of them by N.

EDIT:
You can look at this [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457567/change-size-of-2d-dynamic-array-in-c)

Comment: the values stored before will sustain?

Comment: Yes (read my link above on realloc). Values are preserved, only extra memory is allocated. Does that answer your question ?